# Delay XML Magento header

Tags: xml, magento, php

I have this problem with my own custom design, where I put in some XML code in the header. This XML code seems to be loading first before anything else, and creates a second with an "ugly" page.

I put the code below in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/rokmage-categoryview`

```
<reference name="head">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
  <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>order_history</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>Mine ordrer</label></action>
  <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>special_discounts</name><path>aitloyalty/account/promostats/</path><label>Specielle rabatter</label></action>
      <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>billing_agreement</name><path>sales/billing_agreement/</path><label>Betalingsaftaler</label></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

<reference name="head">
    <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
            <block type="ajaxaddtocart/cart_sidebar" name="ajax_cart_sidebar" template="ajaxaddtocart/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>ajaxaddtocart/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>ajaxaddtocart/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>ajaxaddtocart/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>

            <remove name="wishlist_sidebar" />
            <block type="ajaxaddtocart/customer_sidebar" name="ajax_wishlist_sidebar" as="ajaxwishlist" after="ajax_cart_sidebar" template="ajaxaddtocart/wishlist/sidebar.phtml"/>          

        </reference>
```

But this code is loading before anything else, and is creating some layout problems.

Comment: What XML handle tag did you surround those in?

Comment: I put in the default handle.